# Переменные внутри функции успеха в $.AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Сразу к делу.

```
for (i=0;i < engol; i++){

title = $('.engine-go[data-index='+i+']>h2').html();
engineGo = $('.engine-go[data-index='+i+']').html();
console.log(title);console.log(engineGo);

$.ajax({
url: 'handler.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
    query: 'engineInfo',
    title: title
},
success: function (data){
    console.log(title);console.log(engineGo);
}
})

}
```

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
console.log(title);console.log(engineGo);
```

Этот кусок кода работает, как должен, только в верхней части кода, на 5 строке.
А внутри результирующей функции $.ajax выводит в консоль только последнее значение из массива, проработанное в цикле. 
Если в массиве 14 элементов, наверху он выдаст все 14 разных элементов(как и надо), а внутри функции выдаст 14 одинаковых(последнее значение). Пробовал вынести функцию выше, не делая ее анонимное. Пробовал создавать еще 1 цикл внутри этой функции (значения даются разные, но их 14х14 = 196). Много чего еще пробовал, все без адекватного результата.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать нужный мне элемент внутри результирующей функции $.ajax. Иначе просто не вставить нужное значение из базы.

Благодарю заранее.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы думаете, будто success ждёт исполнения ajax запроса. Ничего подобного. Всё асинхронно. Практически мгновенно отправляются 14 запросов, 13 функций success затираются последней, она и отображает результат последнего запроса. Вам надо или ajax делать синхронным (что не очень прилично выглядит в наше время), либо применить closure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9431643/6817117

Comment: Про closure не понял, но поизучаю. А отключение асинхронности помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: параметр $.ajax - async:false.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var engol = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < engol; i++) {
  let title = "Title " + i;
  console.log("In loop:", title);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("In success:", title);
  }, 200);
}
```